# Configure Jupyter Lab to log kernel interactions

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am trying to figure out a way to capture logs rendered through users interaction with the kernel in Jupyter Lab.

After you `jupyter lab --generate-config` there will be configuration file with a few logging-related options available:

```
c.Application.log_datefmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
c.Application.log_format = '[%(name)s]%(highlevel)s %(message)s'
c.Application.log_level = 30
```

With these, it seems to generate some verbose output in the terminal but can someone point me in direction to help understand the following:

- How can I get this to log into a file?
- This configuration seems to be generating `logging` handlers which could be altered in the notebook code easily - is there a way to get a lower end logger that can not be altered in user code?
- Is this a right way to capture kernel logs (I am looking for something that would capture all the inputs and maybe even outputs sent kernel way)?